# OrderBy section when selecting multiple sections in entries query

Tags: templating, ordering, order, elementquery

When getting pages from multiple sections like so:

```
  {% set aboutNavigation = craft.entries
    .section(['about', 'newsIndex'])
    .all() %}
```

How can I set order that the sections appear?
So I want the `about` pages to be ordered first (by their structure order (which works out the box) and then the `newsIndex` page to be the last page in the order.

How would this also apply if there were more than 2 sections in the array?

Answer (score 2):

I've faced this a few times and solved it like this:

```twig
{% set entries = craft.entries.section([
    'section1',
    'section2',
    'section3',
]).all() %}

{# group the results by section handle #}
{% set entriesGrouped = entries|group('section.handle') %}

{# use this array to specify a manual order to be used when outputting the results #}
{% set manualSortOrder = [
    'section3',
    'section1',
    'section2',
 ] %}

{# ================================== #}

<ul>
    {% for sectionHandle in manualSortOrder %}
        {% if entriesGrouped[sectionHandle] is defined %}
            {% for entry in entriesGrouped[sectionHandle] %}
                <li><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks James. This is a nice approach.

Answer (score 1):

Since posting the original question, I have also solved this like so:

```
{% set aboutPages = craft.entries.section(['about']).all() %}
{% set newsPage = craft.entries.section('newsIndex').one() %}
{% set aboutNavigation = aboutPages|merge([newsPage]) %}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that this approach will increase your query count, as you're making DB roundtrips every time you call .one() or .all().